# Unable to run TYPO3 website to localhost

Tags: php, xampp, typo3, sftp, symlink

Currently I will upload a website to a server, but before I upload it I want to run this website on my localhost (I'm using XAMPP).

They gave me an archive containing the website files, based on the structure of the webfiles I realize TYPO3 is used.
Since I never tried using TYPO3, I tried installing it I followed this steps:
[here](https://www.pagemachine.de/blog/install-typo3-8-0-local-test-system-windows-tutorial/)
 After the installation I run the sample, so far I don't have a problem running it on my web browser.

But when I tried to run the website that I need to upload
I'm getting an error.
here are the files inside the archive.
[image: web files]

Here is after I extract it. As you can see I wasn't able to extract **typo3_src** which is the target location of *index.php*, *t3lib* and *typo3* file that are all both in .symlink type.

And also the **typo3** is not in folder type unlike the sample I run.
[image]

I'm not sure if the archive is broken/corrupted or I need something to do first before it will work. Can someone please help me regarding this issue?

Comment: file system chmod errors perhaps? Make sure uploads is writeable by all users, or atleast the php user.

Comment: No, the folder itself, including the temp one. And typo3 is not there because it is a symbolic link. Something Unix related, kinda like a shortcut but different. So that will not work on Windows.

Comment: Hi sir, for the uploads folder, yes it is writable.

Comment: I see, so then I wont be able to run it in my Windows machine. So i think ill just upload the archive on the server using my ftp client and extract it there. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to deal with those unix symlinks at all.
Just figure out or ask the person who provided you with that system, which version of TYPO3 you need to use. 
Then go to https://sourceforge.net/projects/typo3/files/TYPO3%20Source%20and%20Dummy/ and download the appropriate zip package.
Decompress the package, delete all symlinks (typo3, t3lib, index.php) and just copy the corresponding resources from the package.

You then need to deal with the database and database connection settings in typo3conf/localconf.php or typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php.

If it all works, you can then upload it like this to the server without using any symlinks.